# Communication between three NodeMCUs such that one in in AP mode, second one in AP+STA mode and the third NodeMCU in STA mode

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, nodemcu

I am able to establish a connection between first and second NodeMCU, but unable to do so for the third nodeMCU. I used the IP  address to establish connection.
Should I assign a different IP to each nodeMCU so that communication can take place?
In the code that I had written, i have taken the same IP for all three NodeMCUs, so   communication was possible between 1st nodemcu(in AP mode) and 2nd nodemcu(in STA+AP mode).
For the 3rd node mcu the IP taken was different. Can any one suggest what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

The two network interfaces (station and SoftAP) of the middle esp8266 must have different IP address range. If the top esp8266 has SoftAP with 192.168.4.x, set for the SoftAP of the middle esp8266 IP for example 192.168.5.1. Because with same IP address ranges the esp8266 doesn't know to which network do you want to connect a TCP socket or send an UDP message.

Comment: does it mean that the IP should be same for first and second nodemcu  is same?Also, the IP should be same for second and third nodemcu? Do I need two different IPs for the second nodemcu?

Comment: you have no clue about IP addresses? the STA must have the IP in the range of the AP it connects to. no matter if the AP is a box or a esp8266